# .Was ist richtig aufrestarten oder umstarten?

Tags: translation

Ich bin am versuchen zu Übersetzen „restart the computer“ aus englisch auf Deutsch.

Nachdem sehen verscheiden deutschen Wörter; dessen die Übersetzen von Englischen Wörter, dessen ähnlich mit „re-“ begingt; sein, ich finde auferstarten und umstarten als Kandidaten.

Comment: Normalerweise ist es sinnvoll, erstmal in ein Wörterbuch zu schauen: [to restart](https://www.dict.cc/?s=restart)

Answer (score 4):

Simply say "neu starten". Your suggestions sound a bit weird. For example, "auferstarten" resembles "auferstehen" (to resurrect).

Answer (score 2):

Keins dieser Wörter. Am gebräuchlichsten ist *den Rechner neu starten*, aber auch *rebooten, der Computer rebootet, der Computer rebootete, der Computer hat rebootet*. Bei letzterem Verb wird der Stamm wie das Englische *to reboot* ausgesprochen, die Konjugationsendungen aber deutsch.

Außerdem gibt es *hochfahren — to boot* und *(he)runterfahren — to shut down*. (Beides wird auch für technische Anlagen aller Art verwendet. Bei Chemieanlagen ist aber *anfahren* statt *hochfahren* gebräuchlicher.)

Ebenfalls gebräuchlich sind die Kombinationen *runter- und wieder hochfahren* sowie *aus- und wieder einschalten*.